# Network Adaptro configured with ip address or not? How to check using vc++/Windows api?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, networking, adaptor, iphelper

Hi Could any one share about Network Adaptor configured with ip address or not eithor using dhcp or manual. How to check using vc++/Windows api?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetAdapterAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the **IP Helper** section of Win32.

> The GetAdaptersAddresses function
>   retrieves the addresses associated
>   with the adapters on the local
>   computer.

This returns very detailed information, including DHCP/DNS settings for this adapter, in a list of [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The API is non-trivial to use so follow the docs carefully.

Comment: Thanks for looking in my problem. I will try ur suggestion.